# WP Custom Post Type Output

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I decided to create custom post types in admin menu. So after browsing WP Codex and some forums online I have managed to do it.
[image: WP Admin Page with custom post type Projects]

I have added following code to achieve such a little task:

```
/**
 * Register a book post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_book_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Projects', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Projects', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Projects', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Project', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Projects', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Project:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'  => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'projects' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'supports'           => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes')
    );

    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );

function create_book_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'project-types',
        'projects',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Project Types' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'project-types' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );
```

I have managed to display posts from custom post type on my home page:

```
 <?php query_posts('post_type=projects');
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <div class="project-module">
                        <a class="project-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <div class="project-module-title">
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But there is a problem. WP says that "PAGE NOT FOUND" when I click on the post to view it.
I have tried to create single-projects.php or archive-projects.php and nothing helps.
What do I missing here?

Comment: have you tried recreating your permalinks? that's often times an issue with custom post types.

Comment: haha. it works. I spend hours today trying to work out what's wrong. thanks. Do I have to update permalinks if I will make another post type?

Comment: It's just something I figured out myself the hard way. I usually do it only, when having some problems ,-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebuild your rewrite rules.

In admin go to **Settings → Permalinks** and press **Save Changes**.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Answer (score 1):

According to WordPress Codex, you need to manually run `flush_rewrite_rules()` once manually for new custom post types.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules